# The multi-part identifier 'T1.[AcctName]' could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alias

I am trying to get result from query written below.from this i am getting the error

> The multi-part identifier "T1.AcctName" could not be bound.

I dont know why it is giving so. please help out.

```
SELECT T1.[AcctName],
       SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS buget
FROM OBGT T0
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Consultants%' THEN 'Consultants'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Patient%' THEN 'Patient Care'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Equipment%' THEN 'Equipments' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Expense%' THEN 'Other Expenses' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Alteration%' THEN 'Alterations/Renovations'
                ELSE 'Alterations/Renovations'
           END as [AcctName],
           [AcctCode]
    from OACT
    ) as T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
where T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY T1.[AcctName]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove alias in subquery:

```
SELECT T1.[AcctName],
       SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS buget
FROM OBGT T0
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN [AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
                WHEN [AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
                WHEN [AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies'
                WHEN [AcctName] LIKE '%Consultants%' THEN 'Consultants'
                WHEN [AcctName] LIKE '%Patient%' THEN 'Patient Care'
                WHEN [AcctName] LIKE '%Equipment%' THEN 'Equipments' 
                WHEN [AcctName] LIKE '%Expense%' THEN 'Other Expenses' 
                WHEN [AcctName] LIKE '%Alteration%' THEN 'Alterations/Renovations'
                ELSE 'Alterations/Renovations'
           END as [AcctName],
           [AcctCode]
    from OAC
    ) AS T1
   ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
where T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY T1.[AcctName];
```

The point is alias `T1` is defined outside subquery so it is not visible inside.

Alternatively you can add alias inside like:

```
SELECT T3.[AcctName],
       SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS buget
FROM OBGT T0
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Consultants%' THEN 'Consultants'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Patient%' THEN 'Patient Care'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Equipment%' THEN 'Equipments' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Expense%' THEN 'Other Expenses' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Alteration%' THEN 'Alterations/Renovations'
                ELSE 'Alterations/Renovations'
           END as [AcctName],
           [AcctCode]
    from OACT AS T1
    ) as T3 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T3.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
where T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY T3.[AcctName]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am going to rate this answer. when i use another select statement in main select like SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS buget,(Select sum(T3.[Debit]/85) From JDT1 T3 where T2.[Name] = 'July-Dec2015' ) as 'CurrentBudget'  then i am getting Column 'OBGS.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. can you tell how it can be handle. please

Comment: Looks like your initial problem is solved, isn't it? As for your comment, that would be a different question, consider posting it separately.

Comment: i am able to ask another question so soon. please if you can tell.

Comment: @Kirat Debuging with comments is not how SO works. But you can try to a) add `OBGS.Name` to `GROUP BY ..` or b) Use `MAX(OBGS.Name)`